# Unhandeld exception in production System.Net.Http 4.1.1.1 FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, nuget-package, filenotfoundexception

This error only pops up when I publish my .Net 4.6.2 console application and install it on a remote Win 2012r2.

> Onverwerkte uitzondering: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Kan bestand of assembly Sy
>   stem.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a of e
>   en van de afhankelijkheden hiervan niet laden. Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand
>   niet vinden. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Kan bestand of assembly System.Net
>   .Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a of een van d
>   e afhankelijkheden hiervan niet laden. Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vin
>   den.
>      --- Einde van intern uitzonderingsstackpad ---
>      bij Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Http.DefaultHttpClient.Initialize(IConnection
>   connection)
>      bij Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Transports.TransportHelper.GetNegotiationRespo
>   nse(IHttpClient httpClient, IConnection connection, String connectionData)
>      bij Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Transports.AutoTransport.GetNegotiateResponse(
>   IConnection connection, String connectionData)
>      bij Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Transports.AutoTransport.Negotiate(IConnection
>    connection, String connectionData)
>      bij Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Connection.Negotiate(IClientTransport transpor
>   t)
>      bij Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Connection.Start(IClientTransport transport)
>      bij Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Connection.Start()
>      bij CasaCommon.HouseContext..ctor()
>      bij ConsoleApp4.Program.GetOperator()
>      bij ConsoleApp4.Program.Main(String[] args)

Unfortunately I have the dutch lang pack installed. But it says: unhandled exception. Can't find file or assembly system.net.http or one of the dependencies.

I have a console app with the nuget `System.Net.Http 4.3.2` (latest) but this seems to happen with something `Signalr.Client` related which is in my Class Lib (.Net 4.6.2) project. There is a `Signalr.Client` nuget 2.2.2 which depends on **Microsoft**.Net.Http so I did not had a nuget/ref to `System.Net.Http` in that class lib. Because of this error, I added the nuget for `System.Net.Http` 4.3.2 but that did not solve it. The error is still the same. I can't even downgrade 4.3.2 to 4.1.1.1 because there is only 4.1.1

When I downgraded to 4.1.1 the error is still the same and `System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.4.0.0` is installed. So no matter what I try. I keep getting this error in production. Works on my machine...
I have read something about removing the default ref in the references node in the solution explorer. [Why I can not use System.Net.Http package in a solution with System.Net.Http reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45333166/why-i-can-not-use-system-net-http-package-in-a-solution-with-system-net-http-ref)
But that did not solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to comment out this piece in app.config of both the console app project and the class lib project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <!--<dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.1" newVersion="4.1.1.1" />
            </dependentAssembly>-->
       </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

It was somehow auto added to both `app.config` files. I know that I did not add those lines myself.