# How to use SignalR as client in windows service? (File not found exception: at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Http.DefaultHttpClient.Initialize)

Tags: c#, service, signalr, signalr.client

I'm going to use SignalR in a windows service as client.

Service is running under administrator privileges.

And "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client" package added by nuget.
running code as windows application has no errors and runs correctly. but when I install it as service, service stops and in windows Events I can see this error.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45708150/6363853) answer did not resolved my problem.

```
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Http.DefaultHttpClient.Initialize(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.IConnection)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Transports.TransportHelper.GetNegotiationResponse(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Http.IHttpClient, Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.IConnection, System.String)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Transports.AutoTransport.GetNegotiateResponse(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.IConnection, System.String)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Transports.AutoTransport.Negotiate(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.IConnection, System.String)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Connection.Negotiate(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Transports.IClientTransport)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Connection.Start(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Transports.IClientTransport)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Connection.Start()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but when I catch error, the error text changes and says System.Net.Http is missing.

And I don't know why it runs perfectly as widows application, but not in service.